# CSS on Master page overwriting CSS on local page

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a CSS file on a master page(`mpcss.css`).
On one of the content pages I need a totally different style set for most of the controls.
Here I created a new CSS file named `contentcss.css` and included it in the content place holder:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="JQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Styles/ssjquery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
```

But still the CSS from the master page is overwriting the local CSS. How do I fix this issue?

**EDIT:** I do not have inline styling. I have 2 different CSS files, `mpcss.css` and `contentcss.css`:

**CSS on masterpage**

```
<head runat="server">
    <link href="~/Styles/mpcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

**CSS on content page**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="JQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Styles/contentcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS as the name suggests is cascading, meaning that whoever comes last will override the rest.

So, if you have two css files:

```
<link href="Styles/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Styles/newone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in that case newone.css rules will override the master.css rules.

Please note, that if you have inline styling (i.e. style tag in the html itself) css cannot override these values.

Answer (score 0):

IF you mean that the css in your master page is in-line, then your external css file will not over ride the in-line styles.  Try to stray away from in-line styling if this is the case.

Comment: Docbrand, masterpage uses a file called mpcss.It is not inline styling. This specific page uses contentcss. There are 2 different css files.